# "Print to printer" functionality in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add "print" button to print simple reports in a plugin. The basic idea I have is to generate a printer friendly html page and redirect user to that page where he/she can use browser's print functionality.

How good is that solution? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Have you reviewed the wealth of info on the [Styling for Print](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_for_Print) codex page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [**WP Print Friendly**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-print-friendly/) plugin which extends WordPress template system to support printer-friendly templates. Works with permalink structures to support nice URLs.